# trouble running all thread group within test plan during Jmeter's remote testing

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup, distributed-testing

i am having trouble with remote testing in jmeter.

my server is able to ask the client to start the test plan.

However, only the first active thread group is running, the rest of the active thread group did not run at all.

is there anything that i might have missed??

I did not tick "Run thread group consecutively"

Comment: Can you show your test plan and jmeter.log ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help, but i solved it myself. my CSV Dataset is a invalid location, making the rest of the thread group to not run at all.